# Error rendering superform control

Tags: obout

I am tying to add the Obout Suite superform control to my webpage.
The control is not rendering on the design page.
It gives an **error** saying

> > There was an error rendering the control. Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

I have added the `@Register` directive:

```
 (<%@ Register TagPrefix="obout" Namespace="Obout.SuperForm" Assembly="obout_SuperForm" %>)
```

to the top of my page.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?